# How are on and off bipolar cells of the retina arranged?

Tags: neuroscience, physiology, eyes

In the retina, there are both on and off bipolar cells. But how are they spread out in the retina? Are they so, that there is one of each after one another? Or are there areas where there are clusters of just on bipolar cells and other clusters of only off bipolar cells?